# Stripping punctuation from text in Python

Tags: python, string, mapreduce, nlp, special-characters

I am trying to get the tokens (words) from a textfile and strip it off all punctuation characters. I am trying the following:

```
import re 

with open('hw.txt') as f:
    lines_after_254 = f.readlines()[254:]
    sent = [word for line in lines_after_254 for word in line.lower().split()]
    words = re.sub('[!#?,.:";]', '', sent)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things here in your script. You are not tokenizing, but splitting everything into single chars! Also, you are removing special chars after splitting everything into chars.

A better way would be to read the input string, remove the special chars and then tokenize the input string.

```
import re

# open the input text file and read
string = open('hw.txt').read()
print string

# remove the special charaters from the read string
no_specials_string = re.sub('[!#?,.:";]', '', string)
print no_specials_string

# split the text and store words in a list
words = no_specials_string.split()
print words
```

Alternatively, if you want to split into tokens first and then remove special characters, you can do this:

```
import re

# open the input text file and read
string = open('hw.txt').read()
print string

# split the text and store words in a list
words = string.split()
print words

# remove special characters from each word in words
new_words = [re.sub('[!#?,.:";]', '', word) for word in words]
print new_words
```

Answer (score 2):

re.sub is to be applied to string and not list!

```
print re.sub(pattern, '', sent)
```

should be

```
print [re.sub(pattern, '', s) for s in sent]
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Use the `remove_puncts()` function below

```
import string
translator = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)
def remove_puncts(input_string):
    return input_string.translate(translator)
```

Example usage

```
input_string = """"YH&W^(*D)#IU*DEO)#brhtr<><}{|_}vrthyb,.,''fehsvhrr;[vrht":"]`~!@#$%svbrxs"""
remove_puncts(input_string)
'YHWDIUDEObrhtrvrthybfehsvhrrvrhtsvbrxs'
```

**EDIT**

*Speed Comparisons*

Turns out using the `translator` approach is faster than substituting using regular expressions

```
import re, string, time

pattern = '[!#?,.:";]'
def regex_sub(input_string):
    return re.sub(pattern, '', input_string)

translator = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)
def string_translator(input_string):
    return input_string.translate(translator)

input_string = """cwsx#?;.frvcdr"""
string_translator(input_string)
regex_sub(input_string)

passes = 1000000
t1 = time()
for i in range(passes):
    a = string_translator(input_string)

t2 = time()
for i in range(passes):
    a = regex_sub(input_string)

t3 = time()

string_translator_time = t2 - t1
regex_sub_time = t3 - t2

print(string_translator_time) # 1.341651439666748
print(regex_sub_time) # 3.44773268699646
```

Answer (score 0):

nothing is being read into your list

```
In [14]: with open('data', 'r') as f:
    ...:     l=f.readlines()[254:]
    ...:     

In [15]: l
Out[15]: []
```

assuming you want a list of words, try this

```
with open('data', 'r') as f:
     lines = [line.strip() for line in f]

sent= [w for word in lines[:254] for w in re.split('\s+', word)]

find = '[!#?,.:";]'
replace = ''

words = [re.sub(find, replace, word) for word in sent]
```

as @Keerthana Prabhakaran pointed out the re.sub has been corrected

Comment: This still retains the error!

Comment: The error is  `return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)` and here the `sent` is a list!!